# Main open computational problems in quantifier elimination?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic, model-theory, computer-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry

A language is said to have *quantifier elimination* if every first-order-logic sentence in the language can be shown to be equivalent to a quantifier-free sentence, i.e., a sentence without any $\forall$s or $\exists$s. An example is the theory of real closed fields (such as $\mathbb{R}$), considered with the four basic operations, equality ($=$) and inequalities ($<$, $>$).

Question: how fast could an algorithm that does quantifier elimination be? By how much are current algorithms (such as the ones that proceed by cylindrical decomposition) worse than the best algorithms that are conceivably possible? What are, in brief, the main open computational problems in quantifier elimination?

(We can try to restrict the discussion to $\mathbb{R}$, though other "useful" theories also interest me.)

As far as I know, the situation is as follows: in general, there are first-order sentences on $k$ variables that are not equivalent to any quantifier-free sentences of length less than $\exp(\exp(C k))$; this means, in particular, that the worst-case performance of a quantifier elimination program has to be at least doubly exponential on $k$. This is matched by cylindrical-decomposition algorithms (correct me if I am wrong). At the same time, if the original formula contains only $\exists$s or only $\forall$s, then an algorithm that is singly exponential on $k$ is known. (I'm going by a very quick reading of Basu, Pollack, Roy, Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry; all errors are my own.)

The second case - on which exponential bounds are known - is important, since it covers all cases of the form "prove this formula holds for all $x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_k$".

Is this the end of the story, or is there a subarea where plenty of work could remain to be done?

---

Well, there seems to be real interest in this question, but no answer as such yet. Let me suggest what would be very nice as an answer: a few open problems on the subject, hard but not impracticable, with statements that are neat enough for mathematicians yet also close enough to actual practice that their solution would likely be useful.

For example: would reducing the existential theory of $\mathbb{R}$ to $k$-SAT be such a problem?

Comment: Some of the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115608/sat-and-arithmetic-geometry/115625#115625 describe the known complexity results for the existential theory of the reals.

Comment: In short, for the problem with only $\exists$s, we know that (a) the problem is in PSPACE, (b) the time complexity is no worse than exponential (and we have the algorithm), (c) the problem is not much worse than NP. Does this mean that, for instance, we do not know whether the problem is in P? Is it conceivable or plausible that it could be in P? (Say, is it NP-complete?)

Comment: It is known to be NP-Hard by the 3-sat reduction in the question linked above. So it cannot be in P unless P=NP.

Comment: I wouldn’t be so sure about “the problem is not much worse than NP”. We sort of know this for the existential theory of $\mathbb C$, but reals are much more intricate due to the presence of order. I’m not aware of any results indicating the existential theory of $\mathbb R$ should not be PSPACE-complete.

Comment: Well - what would be your guess for the complexity of the existential theory of $\mathbb{R}$? What is the strongest plausible guess - is it conceivable that one could find an algorithm that is worse than polynomial but much better than exponential (say, $e^{n^\epsilon}$, or even $e^{(\log n)^k}$)? Surely that would have applications.

Comment: (Let me get this right - 3-SAT can be reduced either to the existential theory of $\mathbb{C}$ or the existential theory of $\mathbb{R}$? I'm reading that 3-SAT is not believed to be solvable in less than exponential time.)

Comment: The problem is of course believed not to be computable in subexponential time on a deterministic Turing machine, due to its NP-hardness, but this says nothing about whether its complexity is closer to NP or to PSPACE. Both NP and PSPACE are assumed to require exponential deterministic time, so this is no good as a complexity measure in this range.

Comment: Would proving that the existential problem over $\mathbb{R}$ is in NP be worthwhile? Useful?

Comment: (And, forgive me for asking, are all NP-hard problems believed to be not computable in subexponential time? I thought there were actual counterexamples to this.)

Comment: First, the proper definition of exponential time is $2^{n^c}$ for some constant $c>0$. The version with $2^{cn}$ is not robust, it is not invariant by trivial manipulations like representing the input in a slightly different way. With this definition, all NP-problems are assumed to require exponential time. (This is obviously impossible with $2^{cn}$, as just by padding the input from $n$ to $n^c$ bits, any NP problem solvable in time $2^{cn}$ can be turned into an NP-problem solvable in time $2^{n^{1/c}}$ (where $n$ is the new length of the input)). Having said that, 3SAT is assumed to ...

Comment: .. require time $2^{cn}$ for some $c>0$, where $n$ is the number of variables. The reduction to $\mathbb R$ preserves the number of variables, so if you take $n$ to be this parameter, the same bound would apply there. As for the first question, the difefrence between NP, other levels of the polynomial hierarchy, PSPACE, etc., make a lot of difference in the complexity theory. If we are going to study the complexity of a problem at all, it is of course desirable to solve the question completely by locating its place in the hierarchy. . This is a mathematics Q&A site, not an engineering one, ...

Comment: ... but just in case you meant your question in a practical push-button software way, yes, it is often quite useful. While SAT may need exponential time in the worst case, practically occurring instances tend to be solvable more easily, and there is a huge industry around building efficient SAT solvers. For many NP problems these days, it is much faster to translate the problem to clauses and throw it onto a state-of-the-art SAT solver rather than implementing any special-purpose algorithm for the problem. You can’t do this if you don’t even know whether the problem is reducible to SAT.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, showing reducibility to $k$-SAT ($k$ bounded and preferrably small) would be a worthwhile goal, both practically and theoretically - and it is both nontrivial and plausible. Is this right? What other goals (within this problem area) have similar characteristics, or are equally good in some other sense?

Comment: The problem of the current approach in this area is that in the simplest case of checking non-emptiness of a real algebraic set one ends up chasing roots of a univariate polynomial of degree at least the number of connected components of the set. An interesting topic might be to try to bridge it with the sums of squares-based methods in real algebraic geometry. (Which are in practice computationally more feasible, by using semidefinite programming). This of course opens a Pandora box of exactness etc...

Comment: Dima, this sounds very interesting - can you try putting it in the form I suggest below?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem of the current approach in this area, exemplified by the book by [Basu, Pollack, Roy, "Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry"](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html) is that one ends up with the simplest case: checking non-emptiness of a real algebraic set $S$, and the only well-analysed class of algorithms to solve it leads to chasing roots of a univariate polynomial of degree at least the number of connected components of $S$. Even worse, if $S=V_{\mathbb{R}}(f_1,\dots,f_k)$ then instead of looking at the ideal $(f_1,\dots,f_k)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ one looks at $V_{\mathbb{R}}(\sum_{j=1}^k f_j^2)$, which leads to blowing up degrees by 2.

An interesting topic might be to try to bridge it with the sums of squares-based methods in real algebraic geometry. (Which are in practice computationally more feasible, by using semidefinite programming). The latter can be read about in e.g. ["Semidefinite Optimization and Convex Algebraic Geometry"](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611972290).

There are many open problems in the latter itself, some of them of number-theoretic flavour. E.g., understand when a polynomial $f$ with rational coefficients $f=\sum_{j=1}^m h_j^2 \in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, with each $h_j\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ (i.e. $f$ is a sum of squares of polynomials with real coefficients) can be a sum of squares of polynomials with rational coefficients, $f=\sum_{j=1}^{m'} g_j^2$,  with each $g_j\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$. The state of the art on this problem is here in the [talk by C.Scheiderer](http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/POP/seminars/2013072310002.pdf).

A much more famous open problem there is the complexity of the feasibility problem for linear matrix inequalities: decide the emptiness of $$S(A_0,\dots,A_m):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^m\mid A_0+\sum_{j=1}^m x_j A_j\succeq 0\},$$ where $A_j$ are symmetric matrices, and $B\succeq 0$ stands for "$B$ is positive semidefinite". See e.g. [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2437002). There has been no progress on this problem since Ramana's 1997 [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07001370#bib10). The related problem is *semidefinite programming*, a.k.a. SDP: minimize a linear function on $S(A_0,\dots,A_m)$. It is a natural generalization of linear programming (LP), and has become very popular in various areas due to its expressive powers.  Chapter 2 of [this book](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611972290) is an accessible introduction to SDP.

The relation between the SDP and the feasibility problem for linear matrix inequalities is akin to the relation between LP and feasibility problem for "ordinary" linear inequalities. Namely, one can solve the minimization problem efficiently iff one can solve the feasibility problem efficiently, this is well-known as "equivalence of optimization and separation". 
Khachiyan and Porkolab wrote a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07001370#bib9) where one can find a number of constructions illustrating how much more delicate $S(A_0,\dots,A_m)$ are, compared to "ordinary" polyhedra.

Comment: Can you give us a few more references on the "famous open problem"?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include more references. HTH.